# syntax explanation for javascript browser detection with navigator.userAgent

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-detection

What is the below syntax doing? More specifically, what exactly is the / and the i.test(navigator.userAgent)? Is this jquery stuff? Thanks!

```
    if(( /(ipad|iphone|ipod|android|windows phone)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
/(ipad|iphone|ipod|android|windows phone)/i
```

is a [regular expression literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). In this case, it's a expression that will match any of the substrings `ipad`, `iphone`, `ipod`, `android`, or `windows phone`. The `i` modifier at the end makes it case-insensitive.

This:

```
.test(navigator.userAgent)
```

is calling the `test()` method on that object. So it's checking whether `navigator.userAgent` contains any of the strings mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.userAgent` gives you the string that hold the details of browser, OS etc. Something like this

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36

And the **regex detect** if one of if them is found in the string or not. If found the condition become `true` else `false`.